# only one of two css files is in effect in angular 2 app

Tags: html, css, angular

I am following a tutorial on angular 2, and at some point i had to use bootstrap classes. In the external libraries folder, bootstrap exists but it didn't seem to work. To solve that i imported it in the `index.html` file, and although it now works, my other css file doesn't. These are the contents of `index.html` (css files in lines 6-7):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

also here is the part where i use the bootstrap classes:

```
 template: `
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <i class="glyphicon" 
        [class.glyphicon-star] = "isFull" 
        [class.glyphicon-star-empty] = "!isFull" 
        (click)="onClick()"> 
    </i>    
  `
```

and finally `styles.css`:

```
h1 {
  color: #369;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 250%;
}
body {
  margin: 2em;
}
```

Comment: You mean both not working together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have heard about `ViewEncapsulation` metadata property of @Component.
You can use it like this for bootstrap to work with your custom style:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.none,
    styleUrls:  ['styles.css'],
    ...
    ...
})
```

Check out my working demo,

http://plnkr.co/edit/oQYg5EFgaxoWdYyD8yhl?p=preview

Comment: thanks :) . Also one more question. I've seen in the tutorials that they have a `boot.ts` file in their app folder, and i don't have that. Is it important?

Comment: its just a file name. you can have other name of the file. its not compulsory...its just contains `bootstrap function` nothing else... you can implement it your desired way without any prbm...